# Time expression immediately after the subject?

Tags: syntax

I read the following in NY Times today, but the part on Monday doesn't sound right to me? On the other hand it seems wrong to question NY Times.

> The Biden administration **on Monday** is expected to formally accuse the Chinese government of breaching Microsoft email systems used by many of the world’s largest companies, governments and military contractors, according to a senior administration official.

Comment: It is a strange word order, I agree. I would place "on Monday" either at the beginning (best option), or after "expected".

Comment: And as well as @fev suggestion I would move the phrase starting _according_ to the front before _on Monday_. It still does not read very well even then.

Comment: It would be unusual in speech and in most written contexts. However, the language of newspaper journalism is not always normal English. It rarely uses opening modifiers, and in this sentence, "on Monday" cannot be positioned later without accidentally modifying the wrong phrase. So this is what we're left with.

Comment: Putting the time adverbial immediately after the subject is very common in journalism. The two most important parts of a story are usually the topic and the time, in that order, and this structure allows them to be placed there in the opening sentence. It's unnatural just about everywhere else in English.